# When should a FormControl be marked as pristine?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I had a discussion on how forms should act with a coworker and we had differing ideas on how a backend driven input field should respond to user input.

This discussion was based on [Angular's definition of pristine](https://angular.io/guide/forms#show-and-hide-validation-error-messages)

> "pristine" means the user hasn't changed the value since it was displayed in this form.

So given a user has an autocomplete input that looks up airports nearby, when the user selects an option then we set the value of the `FormControl` to the selected option.

It's my understanding that since the user chose the option, then the FormControl was changed by the user.

My Coworker's understanding is that the change is programmatic, and the `FormControl` is updated based off some backend process, so therefore the value is "trusted" and is marked pristine.

Is there a more concrete definition of pristine? One that takes into account backend processes or programmatic inputs?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the answer lies [in the documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/0075017b43a37d06780cc245c3326212d15fd6bd/packages/forms/src/model.ts#L284) of the `pristine` property of the `AbstractControl`:

```
  /**
   * A control is `pristine` if the user has not yet changed
   * the value in the UI.
   *
   * @returns True if the user has not yet changed the value in the UI; compare `dirty`.
   * Programmatic changes to a control's value do not mark it dirty.
   */
```

Two things to notice here:

- the user has *not yet* changed the value in the UI
- programmatic changes to a control's value keep the pristine state

Comment: We had an example of where a value had some sort of preset values, like a color picker that had a hex value, but also had some "red", "green" or "blue" buttons as common values. It seems then, those buttons wouldn't mark the input as "dirty" then.

Comment: If these buttons really set the value in a programmatic way with something like `setValue` / `patchValue` / etc. then yes. Something quite similar was discussed also some time ago [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9768) with a good explanation - the goal was to explicitly model the difference between user interaction and programmatic change.